# F#: To Design or not design with mutually dependably record types

Tags: f#, record, mutual-recursion

- I try to model trees with their nodes using F# records.
- Here is an abstraction of what my design looks like:

```ml
type Tree = { Root: Node }
and Node = { Tree: Tree }
```

- (There are other record fields, of course.)
- The rationale is that given a tree I want to quickly access its root node; furthermore, I want to know the associated tree for any given node (including a root node).
- Initializing a tree with its root works:

```ml
let rec newTree = { Root = newRoot }
and newRoot = { Tree = newTree }
```

- Now, I read [in this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42218314/3739381) that this only works because of some accidental `internal` visibility on the backing fields, which also leads that any function initializing such tree/root records must reside within the same assembly as the type definitions (not too great, but I can live with that).
- [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16990906/3739381) describes using `option`s for the mutually dependable fields, but I really want to model that each tree has a root node (no empty trees in my system) and each node has a tree, without having to test for `Some`/`None`.
- **Is my design approach sound?** Or should I rather model the intrinsic bound between trees and their nodes in another way?

Comment: It's usually unnecessary for a node to contain a reference to the tree to which it belongs, so I suggest trying to break the circularity that way first. If you describe the use case, we can help point you in the right direction. In order to assess your design, we need to know more about the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no need to declare a type for root. from a type perspective, a tree *is* a node. the canonical way to define a tree in f# is like so

```
type Node = 
   | N of int * Node list // (inner) node
   | L of int  // leaf

let tree = N(3, [L(5); L(7)])
```

its your choice if you define a separate case for the leaf or simply use

```
type Node = N of int * Node list
```

int is the node data type. you will customize this or even use a generic.

i often use mutable children collections, then i use records like

```
type Node = { data: int; mutable children: Node list }

let root = { data=3; children=[] }
root.children <- [{ data=7; children=[] }]
```